# How To Display JSON Data in flutter syncfusion_flutter_charts

Tags: json, flutter, api, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I am trying to call an api,  to use the data on syncfusion_flutter_charts, but, I am getting an error:
The argument type 'String Function(SensorData, int, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String Function(SensorData, int)'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable).
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
 import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/sparkcharts.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LineChartHum extends StatefulWidget {
  // LineChartHum({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LineChartHumState createState() => _LineChartHumState();
}

class _LineChartHumState extends State<LineChartHum> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadSensorData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              height: 300,
              child: SfCartesianChart(
                zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(
                  //
                  enablePinching: true,
                  enableDoubleTapZooming: true,
                  enablePanning: true,
                  enableSelectionZooming: true,
                  enableMouseWheelZooming: true,
                ),
                primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                title: ChartTitle(text: 'Humidity Sensor'),
                tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
                series: <LineSeries<SensorData, String>>[
                  LineSeries<SensorData, String>(
                    dataSource: chartData,
                    xValueMapper: (SensorData, sensors, _) => sensors.timeStamp,
                    yValueMapper: (SensorData, sensors, _) => sensors.sensorValue,
                  )
                ]
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  
 List<SensorData> chartData = [];
  Future loadSensorData() async {
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(toString());
    // print(jsonString);
    // print(jsonResponse);
    setState(() {
      for (Map i in jsonResponse) chartData.add(SensorData.fromJson(i));
    });
  }
}



Future<String> fetchUsers() async {
  var url = Uri.parse('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/960293/fields/1.json');
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  print(response.body);
  return response.body.toString();
}

class SensorData {
  SensorData({
    this.timeStamp,
    this.sensorValue,
  });
  DateTime timeStamp;
  int sensorValue;

  factory SensorData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SensorData(
      timeStamp: json['timeStamp'],
      sensorValue: json['SensorValue'],
    );
  }
}
```

My API lik:
https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/960293/fields/1.json
How the charts looks:
https://thingspeak.com/channels/960293.
I want it to atleast display as at this link: https://thingspeak.com/channels/960293

Comment: In your JSON result does not find `SensorValue` and `timeStamp` values

Comment: I don't get the point??

Comment: Can you tell me the what/which is the SensorValue and timeStamp value in your json string

Comment: Please, check this link: https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/960293/fields/1.json,    The sensorValue: field1, timeStamp: created_at. Check this image: https://ibb.co/sp4WFdD

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed on your scenario at our end and on checking your code snippet, we found that you have made a syntax error when setting the values for the xValueMapper and yValueMapper properties of the series. Please refer the code snippet below for reference.

```
LineSeries<SensorData, String>(
                    dataSource: chartData,
                    /// Syntax error due to specifying comma (,) between the class and its object_name
                    /// xValueMapper: (SensorData, sensors, _) => sensors.timeStamp,  
                    /// yValueMapper: (SensorData, sensors, _) => sensors.sensorValue,
                   

                    /// Correct Syntax
                    xValueMapper: (SensorData sensors, _) => sensors.timeStamp,  
                    yValueMapper: (SensorData sensors, _) => sensors.sensorValue,
                  )
```

KB: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11674

Comment: That section works now, thanks. I am getting this error: The return type 'DateTime' isn't a 'String', as required by the closure's context.  At xValueMapper: (SensorData sensors, _) => sensors.timeStamp. I am trying to pass the created at value as a timeStamp. check this link: https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/960293/fields/1.json. Am doing anything wrong?